# Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference, parsing json from Jira

Tags: c#, null

I am collecting some data that comes in form of JSON in response from JIRA. When query is executed manually it works.

```
var response = ReturnRestHelper().GetResponse(JIRA_REST_CALL + jql + "&maxResults=1000");
dynamic responseObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
foreach (var test in responseObj["issues"]) // <- Stacktrace points here
```

Same code works for a few other queries that follow the same exact format (and work fine)

Totally at a loss here. Please let me know what may be going on here

Comment: What is in the raw payload?

Comment: It's quite large .. Could it be a timeout?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: It's payload. I'll delete the question tomorrow. Size matters. Who knew :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, folks, the verdict is in. There is nothing wrong with the code, however, due to the size of request timeout becomes a problem. `response` doesn't come back soon enough and the value of `response` is `null`